# How to import data saved in word.doc into R-studio

Tags: r

I've just received a dataset saved in word.doc. The owner of the data did not work with R. I would like to import this data into R-studio. I am familiar with Excel data but never work with word.doc. Is it possible to import this data automatically into R-studio?

Comment: Please note that it is your right to downvote or upvote the question. but it is my right to understand your downvote. Is it because you do not like my question or because something that I should learn?

Comment: You need to transfer it to Excel then to R.  This may help https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/transfer-data-from-word-forms-to-an-excel-worksheet/

Comment: Your question does not eloborate on what you have tried, what type of data (tabular, tekst, tabulated text, images?) that is included in the .doc file, and, frankly, why not just be pragmatic and copy the data to Excel and save as a .csv file (justifiable reason not to: too much data/tonnes of files).

Comment: @MrGumble Thank you for your comment. I do not know how to copy the data to Excel and save as a .csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `officer` is a comprehensive solution for working with `.docx`and `.pptx` files. But if you have the legacy `.doc` format it doesn't work. For that you can use the package `antiword` to import.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please insert an example to help me to understand your answer. Then, I will accept it.